# Copying The Source Code Of Another Element

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a website that I can put some buttons, card designs, image etc... And when I click the button below that material, I want to copy the source code of that material. The project is for accessing the materials quicker that I'm using while coding, and finishing the project faster.

Although I have been thinking for a while, I have not found which method should I use. And if I want to make the project more complicated in the future, I do not want to be a victim of the wrong method that I used before. I would be glad if you can help me with this. In short, I want a button that copies the source code of the 'div' above when it's clicked.

I'm not a native speaker so I am sorry if I have made any grammar mistakes or incomplete sentences.

Thank you.

Comment: Use `.innerHTML` to get the HTML contents of an element.

Answer (score 1):

To copy the source code of an element, relatively simple using an input.

1) Get the element outerHtml which the text from its opening tag to it's ending tag.

```
var elemenSourceCode = ele.outerHTML;
```

2) we need an input, this input can either be hidden in the document since one is enough or we can create one in js add it to the document use it, then remove it.

```
var input = document.createElement('input');
```

3) we set the element outerHTML to the value of the input.

```
input.value = elemenSourceCode;
```

4) Here we append the input to the document, like i side earlier this can be skipped if you have one hidden in the document.

```
document.body.appendChild(input);
```

5) We call `select()` on the input to perform a user like selection.

```
input.select();
```

6) Since there's some text being selected in the document, we call `document.execCommand("copy")` to copy the selected text.

```
document.execCommand("copy");
```

7) By now the text is copied to our clipboard, so we don't need the input anymore.

```
document.body.removeChild(input);
```

## Example Below

```js
document.querySelector('.copy').onclick = () => {
  var button = document.querySelector('.Buttondesign');
  CopyElementSourceCode(button);
};

function CopyElementSourceCode(ele) {
  var elemenSourceCode = ele.outerHTML;
  var input = document.createElement('input');
  input.value = elemenSourceCode;
  document.body.appendChild(input);
  input.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  document.body.removeChild(input);
}
```

```css
/* just for reference */

textarea {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<p><button class="Buttondesign">Button</button></p>
<p><button class="copy">Copy</button></p>
<p><textarea placeholder="try pasting here"></textarea></p>
```

## Hidden input Example

```js
document.querySelector('.copy').onclick = () => {
  var button = document.querySelector('.Buttondesign');
  CopyElementSourceCode(button);
};

function CopyElementSourceCode(ele) {
  var elemenSourceCode = ele.outerHTML;
  var input = document.querySelector('#copyTool')
  input.value = elemenSourceCode;
  input.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
}
```

```css
/* just for reference */

textarea {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<p><button class="Buttondesign">Button Design To Copy</button></p>
<p><button class="copy">Copy</button></p>
<p><textarea placeholder="try pasting here"></textarea></p>



<!-- it has to be somewhat in there, we can't just use display:none; and that will prevent user select like to happen therefore no copying, i mean you can't select what you can't event see, i'm sure there's a lot of ways to hide the input in the doucument -->
<input type="text" style="position:absolute;width:1px;height:0;padding:0;border:none;" id="copyTool">
```

Comment: I've already found a solution just like this. But I really like the way you code, using an arrow function etc... Thanks much, Zohir.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [previousElementSibling](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_previouselementsibling.asp):

```js
var element = document.getElementById('random-element');
console.log(element.previousElementSibling);
```

```html
<div id="div-1">Hi I'm a div</div>
<p id="random-element">Howdy there</p>
```